# Reflection and Generics in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, gson

I've written myself into a corner where I want an instance of `Class<Foo<Bar>>`.  While there's no apparent reason that this shouldn't be valid, there seems to be no way to create one. `Foo<Bar>::class.java` is a syntax error, and Kotlin does not provide a public constructor for `Class`.

The code I'm writing is an abstraction layer over gson.  Below is an overly-simplified example:

```
class Boxed<T : Any> (val value: T)

class BaseParser<U : Any> (
    private val clazz: Class<U>
) {
    //This works for 98% of cases
    open fun parse(s: String): U {
        return gson.fromJson(s, clazz)
    }
    
    //Presume that clazz is required for other omitted functions
}

//Typical subclass:
class FooParser : BaseParser<Foo>(Foo::class.java)

// Edge Case 
class BarParser : BaseParser<Boxed<Bar>>(Boxed<Bar>::class.java) {
    override fun parse(s: String): Boxed<Bar> {
        return Boxed(gson.fromJson(s, Bar::class.java))
    }
}
// not valid: "Only classes are allowed on the left hand side of a class literal"
```

In my production code, there are already dozens of subclasses that inherit from the base class, and many that override the "parse" function Ideally I'd like a solution that doesn't require refactoring the existing subclasses.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, there is a reason this is impossible. `Class` (or Kotlin's `KClass`) can't hold parameterized types. They can hold e.g. `List`, but they can't `List<String>`. To store `Foo<Bar>` you need [Type](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Type.html) (or Kotlin's `KType`) and specifically [ParameterizedType](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/ParameterizedType.html). These classes are somewhat more complicated to use and harder to acquire than simple `Class`.

The easiest way to acquire `Type` in Kotlin is by using its [typeOf()](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.reflect/type-of.html) utility:

```kotlin
typeOf<Foo<Bar>>().javaType
```

Gson supports both `Class` and `Type`, so you should be able to use it instead.

Comment: This answer worked for me.  It didn't meet the goal of not requiring a refactor of all existing subclasses, but I didn't really expect that to be possible.

Type provides the functionality I was expecting from Class, so switching to Type removed the issues I had when trying to use class with generics

Answer (score 1):

The closest you'll get is `Boxed::class.java`. This is not a language restriction but a JVM restriction. JVM has type erasure, so no generic types exist after compilation (thats also one of the reasons generics cant be primitives, as they need to be reference types to behave).
Does it work with the raw Boxed type class?

Comment: For my specific code, no.  Because the constructor of BaseParser<U> calls for  `private val clazz: Class<U>` the compiler won't let you pass anything but an instance of Class<U> for that argument.

Answer (score 0):

For this case, it looks like

```
BaseParser<Boxed<Bar>>(Boxed::class.java as Class<Boxed<Bar>>)
```

could work (that is, it will both type-check and succeed at runtime). But it depends on what exactly happens in the "Presume that clazz is required for other omitted functions" part. And obviously it doesn't allow actually distinguishing `Boxed<Foo>` and `Boxed<Bar>` classes.

I'd also consider broot's approach if possible, maybe by making `BaseParser` and new

```
class TypeBaseParser<U : Any>(private val tpe: Type)
```

extend a common abstract class/interface.